# How add an "and" to the last author

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to add an "and" to the last author for my article, but i don't know how do it.

Please, could anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\usepackage{siunitx}% paquete para manejo de números y unidades
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}% modo de unidades con barra en lugar de fracción de tamaño reducido
\usepackage{booktabs}% para tablas
\usepackage{graphicx}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pgfplots}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pdflscape}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% para gráficos
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}% para gráficos
\newlength\fwidth% definido en el código de Matlab
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}% defino valor de parámetro fwidth de gráficos
\usepackage{tikzscale}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}% para gráficos
\usepackage{overpic}% figuras
\usepackage{tikz}% figuras
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}% setea márgenes de hoja
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 

\journal{Energy Conversion and Management}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Assessment of an Uruguayan oil shale: physicochemical, thermal and morphological characterization}
\author[add1]{Mart\'in Torres\corref{cor1}}
\ead{xxxx@xxx}
\author[add1]{Patrice Portugau}
\author[add1]{Jorge Castiglioni}
\author[add4]{Leopoldo Suescun}
\author[add3]{Luis Yerm\'an}
\author[add2]{Manuela Morales Demarco}
\author[add2]{Bruno Conti}
\author[add2]{Pablo Gristo}
\author[add1]{Andr\'es Cu\~na}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I did in my edit, you can mark your code by pressing the `{}` button in the editor or indenting every code line by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: The lack of an `and` conjunction immediately before the final author (for entries with two and more authors) is determined by the bibliography style -- here, `elsarticle-harv`. If you don't like this style, you should probably either look for a different existing style file or create a new style file from scratch, using the `makebst` utility. Applying anything but a trivially simple hack (and what you're looking to do is not that simple...) to an existing style file should generally be avoided. Have you looked into the `apalike` and `chicago` bibliography styles?

Comment: You're presumbably using the `elsarticle` document class and the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style because you are planning to submit your paper to an Elsevier journal. If that's the case, I definitely would *not* make any changes to the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style.